# How to get user name from cpp in Cmake project?

Tags: c++, c, linux, cmake

I am trying to just get user name. i.e., it's equivalent to `whoami` in ubuntu machine. But I am unable to get. I have tried following snippets.

method-1:

```
std::string get_username() {
    struct passwd *pwd = getpwuid(getuid());
    if (pwd)
        return pwd->pw_name;
    else
        return "(?)";
}
```

method-2:

```
#include<iostream>
#include <cstdio>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    char text[255];
    FILE *name;
    name = popen("whoami", "r");
    fgets(text, sizeof(text), name);
    cout << "Name is : " << text;
    pclose(name);
    cout << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

method-3:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    cout << getenv("USER") << endl;
    cout << getenv("HOME") << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The all methods are returning value as I expected. But, When I integrate this code into my Cmake project, it always returns `root`. I am confused why I am always getting root as response when I try with Cmake.

How to get right value instead of root?

Comment: "System name" I would understand as _hostname_,  and that is not user name, which is the thing reported by `whoami`. Most probably you _run_ your executables as root user.

Comment: I just want username of current user. For ex: in my machine `thasin@thasin-HP-Pavilion-Notebook` When I print `whoami` it returns `thasin`. I just want exactly the same result of what `whoami` returns

Comment: Regarding your title question: _How to get system name_ - will [gethostname()](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/gethostname.2.html) work for your purpose?

Comment: @ryyker - it returns hostname, but my requirement is username

Comment: Did you install the program?, I guess your program is installed as root.

Comment: Please provide the steps you take to build, install, and run your program, including the CMake commands and subsequent build commands. Please include the location of the project on your system and the binaries that you are running, and tell us whether or not you are running as root.

Comment: Think about changing your title :)  System name implies something different than the name of the user on the system.

Comment: @MohamedThasinah: "Program" is a synonym for "executable" - file which is a result of compiling of your cpp file. This file you run (execute) for get its output (user name in your case).

Comment: Did you run program as root? Has your executable SUID set?

Comment: Did you run program as root? Has your executable SUID set?